# Sorting MM-YYYY string using custom comparer

Tags: c#

How to perform sorting on the list of mm-yyyy strings along with mixed words using custom comparer with memory-optimized way.

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
result.Add("04-2020");
result.Add("03-2021");
result.Add("Nan");
```

Comment: What order do you want from that example data?

Comment: It can be asc or descc, customizable based on parameter passed.

Comment: Where do you want those non-dates, before or after the dates? And do you also want to sort them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also want to sort the "non-dates", then you cannot ignore those (building on previous answers):

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
result.Add("04-2020");
result.Add("03-2021");
result.Add("04-2021");
result.Add("2-2021");
result.Add("Nan");
result.Add("Aan");
result.Add("Xan");

var sorted = result.OrderBy(s =>
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M-yyyy",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return (dt, "");
    return (DateTime.MaxValue, s);
}).ToList();
```

This builds a tuple of (DateTime, string), with the date filled in when it did parse, otherwise only the string is filled (with the original string value).

Result:

> 04-2020
> 2-2021
> 03-2021
> 04-2021
> Aan
> Nan
> Xan

Answer (score 6):

You could use Linq as Ran suggested in his answer, and it will work nicely.
However there is another alternative that will probably be more memory-optimized (though admittedly I didn't check):

The `List<T>` type has a built in `Sort` method that have several overloads, [one of them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) takes in a [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=net-6.0) delegate.

Using it will probably be better memory-optimized than using Linq, because you wouldn't need to allocate a new `List<T>`.
Here's one way you can use it (of course, you can use a named method instead of a lambda expression):

```
        result.Sort((a, b) => { 
            var dateA = DateTime.TryParseExact(a, "MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out var dtA) ? dtA : DateTime.MinValue; // change to MaxValue if needed
            var dateB = DateTime.TryParseExact(b, "MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out var dtB) ? dtB : DateTime.MinValue; // change to MaxValue if needed
            return dateB.CompareTo(dateA); // Assending order
            return dateA.CompareTo(dateB); // Descending order
        });
```

Comment: I think that will sort all non-dates in a non-specific order (since they will all be parsed to the same value). If the OP wants the non-dates sorted as well, you'd have to check the return value of `TryParse()` instead, and just return the result of a normal string comparison if `TryParse()` returns false. However, this is clearly better than using Linq if you want it to be "memory-optimized" as per the OP's requirement.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree, but because the OP wasn't very clear on how they wanted the sort to behave in case of non-date values, I didn't try to guess that part. My primary goal in this answer was to show the alternative, non-Linq way of sorting lists, which (I feel) is largely overlooked since dot net first came up with Linq, way back when.

Comment: Yes, probably more memory-efficient... However, as all examples here not optimal in performance:  you're parsing the strings for each comparison... so that will be done multiple times for each of the strings. (Depending on N, )It could be more efficient to first parse all strings, then sort the list, and then convert back to strings.

Comment: @JHBonarius that might make it more time-efficient, but throw memory-efficiency out the window. Alas, you can't always have both...

Comment: Yes, that's wat I was trying to say. I just added it to your answer, as it seems the best... However, for some reason the OP has accepted the last answer.... weird...

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using `Linq` and the use of [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0)

```
var orderedList = result.OrderByDescending(x =>
      DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt)
      ? dt
      : default
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: `orderedList` is not a `List<string>` anymore.... (also, you're missing a `;` after `TryParseExact`)

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled - I modified the answer with your comments

Comment: Bit shorter `(x => DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt) ? dt : default)`

Comment: @Charlieface `dt` will already be default/MinValue if conversion fails.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm aware of that, I was saying the syntax is more concise as you can do it in a single line, and does not require braces `{ }`